# Array of Literal Arrays JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

I have a JavaScript code like that:

```
var faqOpener = {
   defaults: {
      idSelector: "#id",
      id: "2"
   },
...
  if (options && !jQuery.isEmptyObject(options))
     $.extend(this.defaults, options);
...
```

How can I convert that variable as an array of literal arrays something like:

```
var faqOpener = {
   defaults[]: {
      idSelector: "#id",
      id: "2"
   },
...
```

**EDIT:** I will use that defaults variable from another javascript code. As shown in the example it has only one element at array of literal arrays however I should define it correctly and will able to pass variable length(for example array of literal arrays that has 3 array or 1 or more it depends) array of literal arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var faqOpener = {
   defaults: [{
      idSelector: "#id",
      id: "2"
   }],
...
```

Can be used like this:

```
faqOpener.defaults[0].id
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var faqOpener = {
   defaults: [{
      idSelector: "#id1",
      id: "1"
   }, 
   {
      idSelector: "#id2",
      id: "2"
   }],
...
```

or straight

```
var defaults = [{
   idSelector: "#id1",
   id: "1"
}, 
{
   idSelector: "#id2",
   id: "2"
}];
```

The question is rather unclear...

Answer (score 3):

```
var faqOpener = {
   defaults: [
       { idSelector: "#id", id: "2" },
       { idSelector: "#id1", id: "21" }
   ]
};
```

Then you can access the objects in defaults:

```
faqOpner.defaults[0] 
faqOpner.defaults[1]
```

Comment: Maybe the items in "defaults" are gigantic objects

Comment: the "presentation" won't fit on one line

Answer (score 1):

Do you want faqOpener.defaults to be an array of objects { idSelector, id }? In JS, an array literal is delimited by square brackets, so it'd look like this:

```
var faqOpener = {
    defaults: [ 
       {
              idSelector: "#id",
              id: "2"
           },
           {
              idSelector: "#id3",
              id: "3"
           },
        ]
    };
```

That's not an array of arrays, exactly; it's an array of *associative* arrays. An "array" in JavaScript is a particular object type with some special characteristics. Any old JS object is an assocative array.

Comment: Any variable or property in JS can hold a reference to an array of associative arrays -- or more tersely, an array of objects; any JS object is an associative array. Sorry, I should have used that term and saved you some typing! What the answers have given you is how to declare a literal array of objects/AAs. If you've already got such an array from somewhere else, and you just want to assign it to a member, that's the easiest thing in the world: faqOpener.defaults = arrayfromwherever;

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly known as JSON (JavaScript Object Notation):

http://www.json.org/example.html

Comment: Actually, strictly speaking, JSON is a _separate_ markup language that is derived from and that mimicks Javascript's syntax. Though you're right, the syntax will be identical here.